# Getting error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am new to RxANdroid and Retrofit, and getting the following error :

**Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

I have following code in my activity :

```
 disposable.add(apiService.getIncidents(1, "true")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<IncidentResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(IncidentResponse response) {
                        mResponse = response;
                        mIncidentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                })
```

My ApiService looks like following :

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("api/now/v1/table/incident")
    Observable<IncidentResponse> getIncidents(@Query("priority") int priority, @Query("active") String active);
}
```

And IncidentResponse looks like below :

```
public class IncidentResponse {
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Incident> incidents;

    public IncidentResponse() {

    }
    public IncidentResponse(List<Incident> incidents) {
        this.incidents = incidents;
    }

    public List<Incident> getIncidents() {
        return incidents;
    }

    public void setIncidents(List<Incident> incidents) {
        this.incidents = incidents;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your response data look like? The error is stating that your response data does not comply with your model class. So I am guessing instead of getting a list of Incidents, you are getting a single object from the server.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are getting array in json response and you are trying to parse it in object. Solution:

JsonElement yourJson = mapping.get("servers");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Incident>>() {}.getType();
List<Incident> incidentList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the array you are expecting is in fact an object. While you have not shown how your json looks like, it's safe to assume that it is because of the `private List<Incident> incidents;` Try it again but then with `private Incident incident;`